# AngularJS material select box issue on IE11

Tags: css, angularjs, angularjs-material

When I select the `city` drop down on IE11, the background becomes black.

I have attached a screenshot. What is the problem exactly? Is it a CSS issue on else?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: it is a css issue with  IE11.

Comment: Thanks @dkc007 , Can You help me on css  ?

Comment: put plunker or fiddle for details please